# How to combine mulitple column adding '-' and removing '-' with value is NULL

Tags: sql, coalesce, isnull

this is my Data

```
col1    col2    col col3    col4    col5    col6 
42      A       11  18      89      16      empty
42      B       12  empty   89      14      C
36      8       9   empty   empty   2       empty
```

this is the Script I'm running

```
select col1 + COALESCE ([col2]+'-','')
+COALESCE([col3]+'-','')+COALESCE([col4]+'-','')
+COALESCE([col5]+'-','')+COALESCE([col6],'') as totalCol 
FROM ...
```

This is what I get

```
totalCol
42A-11-18-89-16-
42B-12- -89-14-C
368-9- - -2 -
```

This is what I want

```
totalCol
42A-11-18-89-16
42B-12-89-14-C
368-9-2
```

Comment: When you write "empty" in your sample data, do you mean NULL  or do you mean an "empty" string `''`?

Comment: So, you don't want a dash between `col1` and `col2`?  And your data has a `col` that is not used in your query.  So, your query cannot create the `this is what I get` data...  Please clarify.

Comment: yes no dash at Column 1 and 2 basically I'm combing 6 columns into one column and having dashes between them beside the first and second column. and if either of the columns has empty value I don't want the dashes to display like example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run a replace of "- " to "" after your script

also you have to remember that nulls and blank space are two different things.

Updated script

```
select ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(
col1 + COALESCE ([col2]+'-','')
+COALESCE([col3]+'-','')+COALESCE([col4]+'-','')
+COALESCE([col5]+'-','')+COALESCE([col6],'') + ' ','--','-'),
'- ','')))
as totalCol 
FROM ...
```

or  assuming only blank space and not nulls

```
select ltrim(rtrim(replace(
[col1] + [col2]+'-' + [col3]+'-' + [col4]+'-' + [col5]+'-' + [col6] + ' '
'- ','')))
as totalCol 
FROM ...
```

Comment: awesome this worked for the second row but the first row and 3th row I still get a extra - at the end. but not in the middle anymore.

Comment: reply to previous email. the data is empty string  not NULL

Comment: the first script has a - at the end like "42A-11-18-89-16-"   the second script through error " Incorrect syntax near '- '. "

Comment: can you try the first script @john... and for the 2nd script are you able to flick me your statement so i can check. cheers

Comment: Awesome, The first script worked. This is all I needed. Thank you very much. </br> and thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have contrived the data to illustrate the issue (because you have `col` in your data, but don't use `col` in your query), you can easily do it this way.  A dash (`-`) is added after all non-null data.  Then, we pull all but the last character (since it will always be a dash).

I also added more code to create the data, so that you can copy/run the whole query and see that it works.

```
declare @tbl table (
  col1 varchar(10) null,
  col2 varchar(10) null,
  col3 varchar(10) null,
  col4 varchar(10) null,
  col5 varchar(10) null,
  col6 varchar(10) null,
  col7 varchar(10) null
)

insert into @tbl values
('42', 'A', '11', '18', '89', '16', null),
('42', 'B', '12', null, '89', '14', 'C'),
('36', '8', '9', null, null, '2', null)

select left(x.concat_val, len(x.concat_val) - 1) as totalCol
from (
       select isnull(col1 + '-', '') +
              isnull(col2 + '-', '') +
              isnull(col3 + '-', '') +
              isnull(col4 + '-', '') +
              isnull(col5 + '-', '') +
              isnull(col6 + '-', '') +
              isnull(col7 + '-', '') as concat_val
       from @tbl
     ) as x
```

Here's the returned data:

```
totalCol
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
42-A-11-18-89-16
42-B-12-89-14-C
36-8-9-2
```

Comment: this is someone else is data I don't want to change the data type. I want to do this on view. the col name was just an example. not the real column name.